# Mysql ranking rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is kinda hard to explain so I'll do this step by step. Below is the table i've created.

```
id  | item_1 | item_2 | item_3|
32  |   1    |   43   |  54   |
32  |   54   |   32   |  32   |
67  |   42   |   45   |  12   |
```

As you can see, the first 2 rows has the same id, my goal is, get the sum of the first row which is (1+43+54), and the sum of second row which is (54+32+32), then add both rows with the same ID's and sort them up from highest to lowest. I managed to do this with the code below. But what if I want to get the `position` of the row, something like the table below. I am basically doing some ranking system, where I FIRST order them up by the item_sum THEN get the position of the row.  How can I achieve it?

```
position |  id   | item_sum |
    1    |  32   |    218   |
    2    |  67   |    99    |

 select 
      id, 
      sum(item_1+item_2+item_3) as item_sum 
 from yourtable 
 group by id 
 order by item_sum desc;
```

I've tried doing this code below: but the position number are not in order since I set the order by 'item_sum'

```
SET @position=0;
SELECT   @position:= @position+1 AS position,   
          id, 
          sum(item_1+item_2+item_3) as item_sum 
     from yourtable
     group by id 
     order by item_sum desc;
```

Comment: So you expect the returned result to be: `32 - 216, 67 - 99`?

Comment: id 32 sum is 216. how it is 218?

Comment: A column that is called `id` (short for `identifier`) should be a unique property. So there should not be multiple rows that have the same id. If there are, then this column is not an id.

Comment: Unless `id` is a reference to another table? Even still, poor DB design I agree.

Answer (score 2):

you have asked this question already. i have given answer previously. dont know actually what you requirement is......

```
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS position, item_sum , id
FROM (
  select 
      id, 
      sum(item_1+item_2+item_3) as item_sum 
 from yourtable 
 group by id 
 order by item_sum desc
) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2;
```

see the answer. [Here look for what you need](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e5c3/19)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, this should work fine:

```
SELECT `yourtable`.`id` AS `id`,
       `count`.`total` AS `item_count`
FROM `yourtable`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `id`, SUM(`item_1` + `item_2` + `item_3`) AS `total` 
        FROM `yourtable` GROUP BY `id`
) `count` ON `count`.`id` = `yourtable`.`id`
GROUP BY `yourtable`.`id`
ORDER BY `count`.`total` DESC
```

The above will return:

```
+--------+------------+
|   id   | item_count |
+--------+------------+
|   32   |    216     |
|   67   |     99     |
+--------+------------+
```

Please see the [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e5c3/18) for full working demonstration.

Comment: I want a ranking system like, row 1 = position 1, row 2 = position 2, row 3 = position 3, and so on....

Comment: This is what it gives you... You just need to add your own count?

Comment: Yes, I need to add my own count, you didn't specify that in your code